# public available maven repository

Tags: cloudbees

Is it possible to have publicly available read-access maven repository on cloudbees?
I did found a wiki entry on private maven repository http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/CloudBees+Private+Maven+Repository but it clearly states that access to maven repo is only for users wired to cloudbees account.

Looking at the description of the project at https://github.com/arey/hibernate-hydrate which is build by Dev@Cloud and then deployed to cloudbees maven repo, it seems it is possible. 
In my case every time i enter `https://repository-<cloudbees-account>.forge.cloudbees.com` i am prompted for a password. Can anyone help me on this?
Assuming i have 2 cloudbees accounts: A and B, is it possible to have public accessible maven repo for account A and at the same time password protected repo for account B?

UPDATE: I finally got it, on repository page you can define if one of repositories (svn/git/maven repo) is to be public or account access

Comment: If you think you found the answer to your own question, post an actual reply and accept it (which is not only permitted but encouraged on this site).

Answer (score 0):

So regarding Jesse advice i am posting a response to my own questions: 
on cloudbees repository page you can define if give repository (of type maven,svn, git) is accessible (in read only mode) for public access. Originally i was fooled by "maven private repository" name used by cloudbees - it is indeed private (defined specially for your cloudbees account) but it can be publicly accessible.